# Types of property 'min' are incompatible. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number | undefined'

Tags: angular

Just [`npm install ngx-currency`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-currency), copy and paste into app.module.ts from section **set option globally...**,

```
import { CurrencyMaskInputMode, NgxCurrencyModule } from "ngx-currency";
import .... // other modules

export const customCurrencyMaskConfig = {
    align: "right",  allowNegative: true,  allowZero: true,  decimal: ",",
    precision: 2,  prefix: "R$ ",  suffix: "",  thousands: ".",
    nullable: true,
    min: null,
    max: null,
    inputMode: CurrencyMaskInputMode.FINANCIAL
}; 
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NgxCurrencyModule.forRoot(customCurrencyMaskConfig), ...
  ]
})
```

`ng serve` complains

> Types of property 'min' are incompatible.  Type 'null' is not
> assignable to type 'number | undefined'

Angular v14.

**Update**
Removing `min` and `max`, or set them to `undefined` resulting from core.mjs:

> ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(PagesModule)[[object Object]
> -> [object Object] -> [object Object] -> [object Object]]:    NullInjectorError: No provider for [object Object]!

[image]

Comment: Replace null by undefined :)

Comment: Can yu add a screenshot of the error and yur app.module.ts I think yu missed up to import PagesModule  in yur app.module.ts

Comment: @Samba Please see updated above.

Comment: Probably problem of versions

Comment: You are having an issue with `PagesModule` is what the error is saying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In node_modules/ngx-currency/src/currency-mask.config.d.ts,

`min?: number` --> `min?: number|null;`

`max?: number` --> `max?: number|null;`